# Issues when profiling list reversal in Python vs Erlang

Tags: python, list, erlang, profiling, implementation

I was profiling Erlang's `lists:reverse` Built in Function (BIF) to see how well it scales with the size of the input. More specifically, I tried:

```erlang
1> X = lists:seq(1, 1000000).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
 23,24,25,26,27,28,29|...]

2> timer:tc(lists, reverse, [X]).
{57737,
 [1000000,999999,999998,999997,999996,999995,999994,999993,
  999992,999991,999990,999989,999988,999987,999986,999985,
  999984,999983,999982,999981,999980,999979,999978,999977,
  999976,999975,999974|...]}

3> timer:tc(lists, reverse, [X]).
{46896,
 [1000000,999999,999998,999997,999996,999995,999994,999993,
  999992,999991,999990,999989,999988,999987,999986,999985,
  999984,999983,999982,999981,999980,999979,999978,999977,
  999976,999975,999974|...]}

4> Y = lists:seq(1, 10000000).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
 23,24,25,26,27,28,29|...]

5> timer:tc(lists, reverse, [Y]).
{434079,
 [10000000,9999999,9999998,9999997,9999996,9999995,9999994,
  9999993,9999992,9999991,9999990,9999989,9999988,9999987,
  9999986,9999985,9999984,9999983,9999982,9999981,9999980,
  9999979,9999978,9999977,9999976,9999975,9999974|...]}

6> timer:tc(lists, reverse, [Y]).
{214173,
 [10000000,9999999,9999998,9999997,9999996,9999995,9999994,
  9999993,9999992,9999991,9999990,9999989,9999988,9999987,
  9999986,9999985,9999984,9999983,9999982,9999981,9999980,
  9999979,9999978,9999977,9999976,9999975,9999974|...]}
```

Ok, so far it seems like the reverse BIF scales in approximately linear time with respect to the input (e.g. multiply the size of the input by 10 and the size of time taken also increases by a factor of 10). In pure Erlang that would make sense since we would use something like tail recursion to reverse the list. I guess that even as a BIF implemented in C, the algorithm for reversing seems a list to be the same (maybe because of the way lists are just represented in Erlang?).

Now I wanted to compare this with something another language - perhaps another dynamically typed language that I already use. So I tried a similar thing in Python - taking care to, very explicitly, use actual lists instead of generators which I anticipate would affect the performance of Python positively in this test, giving it an unfair advantage.

```py
import time

ms_conv_factor = 10**6

def profile(func, *args):
    start = time.time()
    func(args)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_seconds = end - start
    print(elapsed_seconds * ms_conv_factor, flush=True)

x = list([i for i in range(0, 1000000)])
y = list([i for i in range(0, 10000000)])
z = list([i for i in range(0, 100000000)])

def f(m):
    return m[::-1]

def g(m):
    return reversed(m)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("All done loading the lists, starting now.", flush=True)
    print("f:")
    profile(f, x)
    profile(f, y)
    print("")
    profile(f, x)
    profile(f, y)
    print("")
    profile(f, z)

    print("")

    print("g:")
    profile(g, x)
    profile(g, y)
    print("")
    profile(g, x)
    profile(g, y)
    print("")
    profile(g, z)
```

This seems to suggest that after the function has been loaded and run once, the length of the input makes no difference and the reversal times are incredibly fast - in the range of ~0.7µs.

Exact result:

```
All done loading the lists, starting now.
f:
1.430511474609375
0.7152557373046875

0.7152557373046875
0.2384185791015625

0.476837158203125

g:
1.9073486328125
0.7152557373046875

0.2384185791015625
0.2384185791015625

0.476837158203125
```

My first, naive, guess was that python might be able to recognize the reverse construct and create something like a reverse iterator and return that (Python can work with references right? Maybe it was using some kind of optimization here). But I don't think that theory makes sense since the original list and the returned list are not the same (changing one shouldn't change the other).

So my question(s) here is(are):

- Is my profiling technique here flawed? Have I written the tests in a way that favor one language over the other?
- What is the difference in implementation of lists and their reversal in Erlang vs Python that make this situation (of Python being WAY faster) possible?

Thanks for your time (in advance).

Comment: Note, using a generator approach would *actually be slower* until you get to rather large lists.

Comment: As an aside, expressions like: `x = list([i for i in range(0, 1000000)])`, note `list(<list comprehension>)` is redundant, **list comprehensions already return lists**. But actually, `[x for x in whatever]` is just a wordy way of writing `list(whatever)`, so you just want `list(range(1000000))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This seems to suggest that after the function has been loaded and run
> once, the length of the input makes no difference and the reversal
> times are incredibly fast - in the range of ~0.7µs.

Because your profiling function is incorrect. It accepts variable positional arguments, but when it passes them to the function, **it doesn't unpack them** so you are only *ever working with a tuple of length one.* You need to do the following:

```
def profile(func, *args):
    start = time.time()
    func(*args) # Make sure to unpack the args!
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_seconds = end - start
    print(elapsed_seconds * ms_conv_factor, flush=True)
```

So notice the difference:

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...    print(args)
...    print(*args)
...
>>> foo(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)
1 2 3
```

Also note, `reversed(m)` creates a `reversed` iterator, so it doesn't actually do anything until you iterate over it. So `g` will still be constant time.

But rest assured, reversing a list in Python takes linear time.

Comment: Yikes, how embarrassing! That was a pretty stupid mistake that I made - I should have spent more time looking at the profiling code.

After fixing that, I get a linear trend. Which makes much more sense - esp. with your comment on [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed). Thanks for the help!